# Jquery add option to all the ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Task**:
In my HTML upon changing the options for first select i want to propagate it to all the options with similar id's. So change the option in the rest of the select boxes if it exists or add a new option if it doesnt exit,

```
    $('.script_display').on('change','[id^=suite_]',function(){
  attr = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
  attr_val = $(this).val();
  $('[id^="tc_"][id$="_'+attr+'"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === null){
      $(this).append('<option value="'+attr_val+'" selected="selected" >'+attr_val+'</option>')
      $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
    $(this).val(attr_val);

  });
})
```

upon change in select with ID starts with `suite_` i want to get the value and change/add option to all the ids that starts with tc_ and ends with `"_'+attr+'"'` where attr is shared by both `suite_` and `tc_`

**problem**
This only works every other time i change the option in the `suite_`, i am not able to make this work for everytime there is a change

edit:

```
{% for tag in ['customer','test-phase','modular-pkg','test-type','topology','tgn-type','link-type']  %}
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          {{tag}}: <select style='width:100%' class="action-btn input-lg" name="suite_{{tag}}" id="suite_{{tag}}">
           {% for item in tag_map_ref_yml[tag]['valid_value']: %}
                 <option value={{item}}>{{item}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
          </select>
       </div>
 {% endfor %}

{% for tc in range(1,32) %}
 {% for tag in ['customer','test-phase','modular-pkg','test-type','topology','tgn-type','link-type']: %}
       <div class="col-sm-4">
           {{tag}}:<select style='width:100%' class="action-btn input-sm" name="tc_{{tc}}_{{tag}}" id="tc_{{tc}}_{{tag}}">
            {% for item in tag_map_yml[tag]['valid_value']: %}
               <option value={{item}}>{{item}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
           </select>
       </div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Note:
tag_map_ref_yml will have more options than tag_map_yml

---

solution:

```
$('.script_display').on('change','.suite',function(){
  // Note the use of var here so that they don't become global variables
  // debugger;
  var attr = $(this).attr("data-tag");
  var attr_val = $(this).val();
  $('select.tc[data-tag^="'+attr+'"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // avoid repeating the same jQuery constructor multiple times
    if ($this.val()!==attr_val){
      $this.empty().append('<option value="'+attr_val+'" selected="selected" >'+attr_val+'</option>');
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your HTML so we understand your JS better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial matching on IDs (or really any attribute) is arguably the worst possible way of selecting elements. Instead, add `class`es and/or `data-` attributes that encapsulate each individual aspect you want to search for. For instance, instead of this:

```
class="action-btn input-lg" id="suite_{{tag}}"

class="action-btn input-sm" id="tc_{{tc}}_{{tag}}"
```

Use this:

```
class="action-btn input-lg suite" id="suite_{{tag}}" data-tag="{{tag}}"

class="action-btn input-sm tc" id="tc_{{tc}}_{{tag}}" data-tc="{{tc}}" data-tag="{{tag}}"
```

Then your jQuery becomes much simpler to write and understand:

```
$('.script_display').on('change','.suite',function(){
  // Note the use of var here so that they don't become global variables
  var attr = $(this).attr("data-tag")
  var attr_val = $(this).val();
  $('select.tc[data-tag="' + attr + '"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // avoid repeating the same jQuery constructor multiple times
    if ($this.val() === null){
      $this.append('<option value="'+attr_val+'" selected="selected" >'+attr_val+'</option>')
      $this.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
    $this.val(attr_val);

  });
});
```

Comment: yep data tags did it, but i modified your answer to suite my requirements thanks @Mike McCaughan